# X.shape[1] size doesn't fit the expected value

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I'm currently working on my final degree project in robotics, and I decided to create an open-source robot capable of replicating human emotions. The robot is all set up and ready to receive orders, but I'm still busy coding it. I'm currently basing my code off [this method](https://github.com/amineHorseman/facial-expression-recognition-svm). The idea is to extract 68 facial landmarks from 
 a low FPS video feed (using RPi Camera V2), feed those landmarks to a trained SVM classifier and have it return a numeral from 0-6 depending on the expression it detected (Angry, Disgust, Fear, Happy, Sad, Surprise and Neutral). I'm testing out the capabilities of my model with some pictures I took using the RPi Camera, and this is what I've managed to put together so far in terms of code:

```
# import the necessary packages
from imutils import face_utils
import dlib
import cv2
import numpy as np

import time
import argparse
import os
import sys
if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
        import _pickle as cPickle
else:
        import cPickle
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

from data_loader import load_data 
from parameters import DATASET, TRAINING, HYPERPARAMS

def get_landmarks(image, rects):
    if len(rects) > 1:
        raise BaseException("TooManyFaces")
    if len(rects) == 0:
        raise BaseException("NoFaces")
    return np.matrix([[p.x, p.y] for p in predictor(image, rects[0]).parts()])

# initialize dlib's face detector (HOG-based) and then create
# the facial landmark predictor
print("Initializing variables...")
p = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(p)

# path to pretrained model
path = "saved_model.bin"

# load pretrained model
print("Loading model...")
model = cPickle.load(open(path, 'rb'))

# initialize final image height & width
height = 48
width = 48

# initialize landmarks variable as empty array
landmarks = []

# load the input image and convert it to grayscale
print("Loading image...")
gray = cv2.imread("foo.jpg")

# detect faces in the grayscale image
print("Detecting faces in loaded image...")
rects = detector(gray, 0)

# loop over the face detections
print("Looping over detections...")
for (i, rect) in enumerate(rects):
    # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
    # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
    # array
    shape = predictor(gray, rect)
    shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

    # loop over the (x, y)-coordinates for the facial landmarks
    # and draw them on the image
    for (x, y) in shape:
        cv2.circle(gray, (x, y), 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)

# show the output image with the face detections + facial landmarks
print("Storing saved image...")
cv2.imwrite("output.jpg", gray)
print("Image stored as /'output.jpg/'")

# arrange landmarks in array
print("Collecting and arranging landmarks...")
# scipy.misc.imsave('temp.jpg', image)
# image2 = cv2.imread('temp.jpg')
face_rects = [dlib.rectangle(left=1, top=1, right=47, bottom=47)]
landmarks = get_landmarks(gray, face_rects)

# load data
print("Loading collected data into predictor...")
print("Extracted landmarks: ", landmarks)
landmarks = np.array(landmarks.flatten())

# predict expression
print("Making prediction")
predicted = model.predict(landmarks)
```

However, after running the code everything seems to be fine up until this point:

```
Making prediction
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "face.py", line 97, in <module>
    predicted = model.predict(landmarks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 576, in predict
    y = super(BaseSVC, self).predict(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 325, in predict
    X = self._validate_for_predict(X)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 478, in _validate_for_predict
    (n_features, self.shape_fit_[1]))
ValueError: X.shape[1] = 136 should be equal to 2728, the number of features at training time
```

I searched for similar issues on this website, but being such a specific purpose I didn't quite find what I needed. I've been working on the design and research for quite some time, but finding all the snippets needed to make the code work has taken the most time out of me, and I'd love to polish this concept as soon as possible since the presentation date is approaching quickly. Any and all contributions are greatly welcomed!

[Here's the trained model I'm currently using, by the way.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1K2bqXZSW53kvy-W9jvo1kMBKi1XRrwQf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! Turns out my model was trained using a combination of HOG features and Dlib landmarks, however I was only feeding the landmarks to the predictor, which resulted in the size discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

I am probably being silly, but it looks like you define path *after* you use it to load your model.
Also path seems like a very bad name for a variable containing a file location, perhaps modelFileLocation is less likely to already be defined.

Comment: My bad! I made a slight modification to the code before re-testing it, so I moved the model loading part right before posting, as it seemed better to load all heavy data before doing anything else. I'll edit the post back to a working state! The error mentioned initially persists, however.